# Flutter: How can I resize text based on device's screen size

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, how can I resize text in an app based on device screen size? The app is used for reading text, I need users to see bigger text as their device size increases and also set a maximum possible size. One way I know is doing this;

```
Text(
  'Some text here',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * some_ratio
  ),
)
```

Is there a different way of doing this that will also take into consideration display height as well?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For font size based on screen, I would suggest using `Height` as reference.

for example:

```dart
 double unitHeightValue = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01;
 double multiplier = 25;
 return Text(
  'Some Text', 
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: multiplier * unitHeightValue,
  ),
 );
```

By this approach, you will get Pixel perfect Text size with an additional advantage of a multiplier value of your choice.

This is similar to the `dp` or `sp` concept in Android.

---

**Update**:

After a few additional experiences, I have realised that choosing `Height` as references only works for mobile devices, especially in portrait mode/orientation.

In simple terms when device's main scrolling axis is vertical in device's portrait mode.

So, I would suggest selecting/changing the references as per the need of your application.

i.e. If you are working on an application which is definitely mobile app with only portrait orientation & no rotation support, the above code should work fine without any issues.

However, in case of flutter web support or just rotation support in mobile app, the above approach may not give desired results when user rotates the device.

In this scenario referring to the screen width makes sense for flutter web due to web being accessible to horizontal displays.
But in case of rotation support you may choose to stick with width as reference in all orientation or update the reference based on orientation.

Comment: Why is ```height``` a much better reference than ```width```?

Comment: As far as I know each letter in the alphabets is drawn as a block which is either a square or a vertical rectangle. So, Increasing/decresing the font size affects the height of the letter more than the width. However, This is what I think about why height is a better reference. I may be wrong but this approach has never failed for me.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to use 'Theme.of(context).textTheme.title' to use as a style?

Comment: @abrsh That can also work if we access the `text size` of the `Theme.of(context).textTheme.title` `text style` which we can refer/use to customize further as per our need. However, We need to keep it in mind that this approach depends on the default styles in flutter frameworks which may get changed/deprecated or removed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer, but the solution for me was different. Depends on what you would like to achieve. For me, the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) widget solved most of the problems, because row and other widgets define basic size.

```
AutoSizeText(
 'Text will be resized',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), //just info size
  maxLines: 2, //if needed
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this issue by accidentally using the RichText widget.
you can create a component and pass data like text and style then it will return a RichText widget. It automatically adjusts font size in all screen sizes and looks identical on different screen.

**ResponsiveText.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveText extends StatelessWidget {
  ResponsiveText({
    this.text = 'text',
    this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
    this.style = const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  String text;
  TextStyle style;
  TextAlign textAlign;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      textAlign: textAlign,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

use this component

```
ResponsiveText(
              text: 'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the best answer so far:

```
    final textScale=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01;
    final screenHeight=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    double getHeight(double sysVar,double size){
    double calc=size/1000;
    return sysVar *calc;
    }

    double getTextSize(double sysVar,double size){
    double calc=size/10;
    return sysVar *calc;
    }
    
    Text('lovely family',style: TextStyle(fontSize: getTextSize(textScale, 
    20),),
    SizedBox(height: getHeight(screenHeight, 30),),)
```